# How could I copy data using my own function of copy

Tags: c++, string, binary, char, strcpy

As requested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26118818/how-could-i-copy-data-that-contain-0-character/26118943?noredirect=1#comment40935966_26118943) I'm writing this post:
I'm trying to copy data from `std::string* to *char*` . I'm using C++ .
My approach is to convert `std:string* to *char*` then copy data. But I have a wrong result.
This a part of data to copy :
[image]

My code is the following:

```
CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfEncryptor(cbcEncryption, new CryptoPP::StringSink( ciphertext ) );
stfEncryptor.Put( reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>( plaintext.c_str() ), plaintext.length() + 1 );
stfEncryptor.MessageEnd();

cout << "cipher text plain ("<<ciphertext.size() <<" bytes): " <<std::endl<< std::endl ;
std::cout<< ciphertext <<std::endl  <<std::endl<<std::endl ;
d.body = new char[300];
my_strcpy(d.body,ciphertext.c_str(),300);
std::cout << "Cipher Text length after copy(" << strlen(d.body) << " bytes): " << std::endl<< std::endl;
std::cout << d.body << std::endl<<std::endl;
```

this is my fonction "my_strcpy" :

```
char* my_strcpy( char* arr_out,  char* arr_in, int bloc )
{
char* pc= arr_out;

 for(size_t i=0;i<bloc;++i)     
 {

        *arr_out++ = *arr_in++ ;
 }

 *arr_out = '\0';
return pc;
}
```

Can you give me what is wrong here, please !? 
Whay the result is not as expected !

Comment: The real question is: why do you have to convert to `char*`?

Comment: Because I have many functions that are already writed and they need char* as parameter. And it will be crazy to modify all functions.

Comment: These functions won't work with your data anyway, so you have to rewrite to `std::string` or pass length as additional parameter.

Comment: Your `'\0'` character is out of bounds of the result string, if I'm not mistaken. Maybe that's your problem

Comment: @user1781290 so what I have to do.

Comment: @ Anton Savin: Modify all functions should be my last choice.

Comment: Ok, sry, misread something. While my point above is still valid, your main issue is probably, that `strlen` will just return the number of chars until it hits the first `0` in contrast to `std::string::size` returning the actual buffer size. You need another variable to hold the actual data size

Comment: Sounds like modifying all functions will be your only choice.  This is what happens when your functions are written to take null-terminated char arrays instead of a real string type with some creedence.

Comment: @user1781290: Can you suggest us an answer with your approach.

Comment: @Martin James: But the problem that I'm dealing with binary file. And it isn't advisable to use string with binary file. I'm really troubled. :(

Comment: You know encipherment can/will generate a `0`-byte, *right* ? You need a hex-dump utility function.

Comment: YES yes @ WhozCraig, it is an upvoted answer friend. You can post it as an answer :)

Comment: I still don't understand the problem fully. What kind of functions do you want to call? You either need to modify your binary data to not contain any `'\0'` or you need to modify your existing functions to take a size or `std::string`

Comment: @user1781290, First, I want to copy a cipher text from std::string* to *char*, Besides, I found that not all data was copied. 
When I search, I discover that cipher text can contain null characters by bad chance. And because when I write a char* to cout or calc it's length with strlen they stop at \0 as per C string behaviour, I thought that "my_strcpy" don't work very well in the cause of '\0'.
So I posted do find how can I copy a data that contain '\0'.
IN FACT, the problem wasn't with the way how I copy my data but with the way how I verify my data.